# How to delete matched filenames from a list

Tags: command-line, files, delete

I want to scan for filenames in a **source** directory and all its sub-directoris then print the output to a file like:

```
ls -hR >> del.txt
```

(I, however, don't know how to **not** list folders)

I don't need to save the file's list to a file but I think that will make things safe and clear.

Then, I want a "command" to search a certain **destination** directory and its sub-directories and delete all the matching files in `del.txt` excluding folders.

The files are very different in names and extensions,so using regex won't solve the problem since I want to delete only these files. Also,the directory where I should delete files form has other required files, that I want to keep, with the same extensions as files from the source directory.

Comment: It would likely be simpler to use the `find` command to search for and delete the files directly

Comment: @steeldriver i don't know that's 21000+ files,do you mean using regex cause there is no certain pattern for them?

Comment: OK so please [edit] your question with some context describing what files you are trying to delete. Otherwise there's a chance that this becomes an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: ok i will try to be more clear.

Comment: 1) Does `find . -type f -printf "%f\n" > del.txt`  Give you the output you want? … 2) Do you need to save the list to a file first? Or is it okay to  both search for filenames in the source directory and just pass them to another command to be searched for and deleted from the target directory on-the-fly?

Comment: As @steeldriver suggests, I think using the `find` command is best to find only files without including directories. You can create a script that compares new directory against the old and delete on a match.

Comment: 3) Do you need the subdirectories under the target directory searched for matching filenames and delete them as well or just the parent directory's immediate contents?

Comment: @Raffa 3) yes,i want the sub-directories to be searched as well.and yes that output is what i desire.please go on,you are right on the money. and no i don't need to save them to a file but i think that will make things safe and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the list of filenames from the source directory and save them to the `del.txt` file as null delimited entries like so:

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\0" > del.txt
```

Then dry-run test replacing `/full/path/to/destination/` with the actual full path to the destination directory like so:

```
cat del.txt | xargs -0 -I {} find /full/path/to/destination/ -type f -name "{}"
```

If you are happy with the output, then delete the files with:

```
cat del.txt | xargs -0 -I {} find /full/path/to/destination/ -type f -name "{}" -delete
```

**Alternatively**, you can put the two command in a pipeline to build the list of file names, search for them and print a dry-run on-the-fly like so:

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I {} find /full/path/to/destination/ -type f -name "{}"
```

And delete like so:

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I {} find /full/path/to/destination/ -type f -name "{}" -delete
```

---

**Notice**: A null delimited list of filenames might not be easy to read by humans but is a much safer way for filenames that have a new line in them for example ... You can build a human friendly list **for review purposes**(*i.e. for you to read and keep ... **Don't** use this with the above commands*), like so:

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\n" > my_list.txt
```

Comment: And why might be that **-1** down-vote ... if you would enlighten me ... Please :-)?

Comment: xd def not me,why the hell i would do that to someone give a ... to my problem? but that's so internet attitude you will be thrown as an outcast and you will never know why.i will try your solution when i switch to Ubuntu,cause using git-bash right now,and i don't know how to deal with the "full path" in win 10

Comment: cat del.txt | xargs -0 -I {} find /f/Fallout New Vegas/Fallout New Vegas/Data/ -type f -name "{}"  xargs: argument line too long  am i missing something?

Comment: @leegenny Your destination directory path has spaces ... You need to quote it `"..."` e.g. `... find "/f/Fallout New Vegas/Fallout New Vegas/Data/" ...`

Comment: quote and double quote both doesn't work,i think i have to switch to ubuntu

Comment: @leegenny You didn't use `-printf "%f\n"` did you? ... That's why you see `xargs: argument line too long` ... Use `find . -type f -printf "%f\0" > del.txt` for the command to work ... The other one as I said in the answer is "for review purposes" i.e for you to read and keep **not** to be used with the above commands.

Comment: xd thnx senior Raffa you made me look stupid,it's not a string issue,but the other method worked like a charm.maybe you should reverse the solutions,remove it,or debug it and i will check it if you want.  any way i will mark this as a solution and case closed.  thanks for time Raffa,that was fun.

Comment: @leegenny Files created/edited or even sometimes opened on Windows will most likely not work in Linux due to the windows-style line endings `CRLF` vs. Linux `LF`  ... That could be a reason also ... The two methods are identical except the second method doesn't use a file ... I am glad I helped ... You are welcome :-)